# How to hold negative value into pl/sql variable?

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, plsql

I have a procedure, where i want to declare a variable as number.
This variable is calculated using different columns. 
If the output of calculation is negative how can i hold that negative value into that variable? and I keep getting this error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

```
declare
    out_put_sum number;
begin
    with input as(
        select x.id,x.name,sum(case when ... then abs(x.quantity) as running_total
        from xxxxxx x, yyyyyy y
        where ... )
    select i.running_total into out_put_sum 
    from input i;

    if out_put_sum > 0 then ...
        else ...
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: The same way you would a positive number.

Comment: i keep getting this error msg.ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Comment: I can't see why you're getting that, because you posted no code showing an effort to assign a value. But the error says you're assigning a character to a numeric, which has nothing to do with how to *hold a negative value into a variable*. If you want help with your code, **post your code**.

Comment: Big mistake here. You get an error about "character to number conversion." Where did you come up with the idea that this has anything to do with negative numbers? (You may not be wrong, but you are surely keeping some of the information away from us.) For example, it is possible that data is in string format (it shouldn't be but it is); and some negative numbers don't use a normal dash `-` as you have on the keyboard, but some other sort of "long" dash (em-dash perhaps), which is causing the error. If you don't tell us the WHOLE story we can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(case when......then abs(x.quantity)as 
             running_total
```

Here if you are using `'-'||abs(x.quantity)`  to denote negative value then please refrain from doing so. It will create a String out of it. Use `-1*abs(x.quantity)` instead.

Comment: While your comment is good advice, it does not explain the error the OP received. Indeed, even without being instructed to do so, Oracle **will** convert a string like `'-1.5'` to the corresponding number (*implicit conversion*) if used as the argument to a math function, such as `abs()`.